# Hyperlink in e-mail signature malfunctioning

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, hyperlink, facebook

I'm trying to include a link in my email signature that is directed to our company Facebook page. I know the link works, yet when I try to access it from the signature, I am sent to the Facebook login page:

[image: Screenshot]

Anyone have any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Here is the link I am referring to:

https://www.facebook.com/MidWest-Gloves-and-Gear-188403021210957/

Comment: The screenshot, seems to show an error and is un-helpful. Can you post your signature html..

Answer (score 0):

You have to fool Facebook into thinking that your image link is coming from another web site and not from Outlook.

`<a href="http://tinyurl.com/mwgg20160524"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ccmJU46.jpg"></a>`

The example above is a TinyUrl that goes to the public Facebook company page. When you click on a link from Outlook, Facebook security thinks the referer is odd or missing and will make you go through a CAPTCHA or even block going to the web site all together.

Comment: I failed to mention that what you just suggested, I have already done. It is not only my companies page, every Facebook page I include in the signature produces the same results.

Comment: The signature contains images holding the links to our social media sites. The Facebook link is the only one that isn't working

Comment: The URL is the same as the one I am attaching to my image in my signature. I just included the link to the page I am referring to.

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe your signature is not coded correctly. Review how to make clickable images: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp - You'll have to code the HTML, open the HTML file in Internet Explorer, then copy/paste that into your Signature screen in Outlook.

Comment: It also works fine for me, but when I attach it to my image, thats when the problem occurs.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Im definitely doing something wrong. I can include the link in the signature, but as soon as I assign it to an image, boom, problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40233/discussion-between-sun-and-anthony-sims).